# socket.io events inside express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

To simpify, I actually have the main page (/) and a search page (/search), and in the search page, I want to send information to the user using socket.io, since I only want to send information to one socket, I need the *io.on('connection' ...)*.

This is my code, wich is not working correctly. When I go to */search* for the first time, everything works corectly, but, when I reload, the console logs 'Message #2' two times.

> console

```
First time
----------
Message #1
Message #2

Second time
----------
Message #1
Message #2

Message #1
Message #2
Message #2
```

> server.js

```
var express = require('express');  
var app = express();  
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use( express.static( "public" ) );

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index');
});

app.get('/search', function(req, res) {
    res.render('search');

    console.log('Message #1');

    io.on('connection', function(socket) {

    console.log('Message #2'); // Here's the problem

        getSearch('something', function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("ERROR : ", err);
            } else {
                socket.emit('fetchSearch', data);
            }
        });

    });

});

server.listen('3000');
```

> search

```
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="../favicon.png" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon">

    <title>Title</title>

    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    var socket = io();

    socket.on('fetchSearch', function(rows){
        // Rows is an array
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas on what's happening or how to solve it?

Comment: well, lets see. The event handler runs once, then twice, then three times, so... you must be binding the event handler to the event multiple times. Your code seems to confirm that, each call to /search adds another handler to the connection event.

Comment: You mean if you navigate to /search, you'll see `Message #1` and `Message #2`, but if you refresh you only see `Message #2`?

Comment: How can I change it in order to work? PD: I edited the console logs

Comment: Please post the frontend code for the "search" view.

Comment: You really get 5 messages the 2nd time?

Comment: The first 2 messages are from the first time, i get 3 messages at 2nd time

Comment: In your use case, does everyone receive same "fetchSearch" data upon connecting to `/search` or is it suppose to be unique? If unique, how do you plan to determine what to send back?

Comment: It's unique data, but I don't need to send back the data, just send it to the client.

Comment: And how do you intend to figure out which client gets what data if you are initially sending nothing from the client? It is a random process? Headers? I want to help you with a reasonable example, but there is too much ambiguity. To make things work the way you described it, it seems like you would have to have the server disconnect the client after the request is over or get rid of sockets altogether and just send the data to the client through a regular response.

Answer (score 0):

You have the model a bit backwards.  There is one server and potentially many clients.   As such the server needs to set up a listener ONCE at startup time for incoming socket.io connections.

Then, you place client code in whatever HTML pages you want to create a socket.io connection to the server.  So, the code in the HTML pages determines which pages create a socket.io connection to the server and which do not.  Those pages also decide which socket.io messages to listen for from the server.

The, sometime later when you want to send some specific info to a specific client or to all clients, your server can use `.emit()` to send a particular message to one or more currently connected clients.

The clients that are currently connected and are listening for that message and to whom the message was sent will then receive that message and can act on it.

---

So, in your specific server code, move the:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {...}
```

code outside of any event handler and run it at server initialization.  You never want to run that more than once (which is what you're doing since you have it inside the `/search` event handler so it will add a new event listener for the `connection` event every time the `/search` page is hit.  That's bad and creates duplicate event handlers.  Run it once at server init time.

Then, make sure that the `/search` page contains Javascript to create a socket.io connection to the server.

Then, you will be ready to send messages at any future time from your server to any browsers that that currently have the `/search` page loaded.

---

Then, in your `/search` route handler on the server, you  have to decide exactly what you're trying to do.  You can't send data to a socket.io connection for the `/search` page from the route handler for `/search` because the browser has not yet even received or loaded the `/search` page yet so there's no page yet (and corresponding socket.io connection in that page) to send to.  If you're just trying to populate the response from `/search` with data, then you should just put that data in the http response itself and not use socket.io for that.  socket.io should be for further updates to the page AFTER it has been loaded by the browser and after the http response is long since done.